# Register generic factory for all types which implements an interface

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, autofac

I have generic factory

```
public interface IViewModelFactory<T> where T : IViewModel
{
    T Create<TU>(TU par);
}

public class ViewModelFactory<T> : IViewModelFactory<T> where T : IViewModel
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _scope;

    public ViewModelFactory(ILifetimeScope scope)
    {
        _scope = scope;
    }

    public T Create<TU>(TU par)
    {
        return _scope.Resolve<T>(new TypedParameter(typeof(TU), par));
    }
}
```

which I can use for resolving  viewmodel factory in my window class:

```
public WRPersons(IViewModelFactory<MRPersons> viewModelFactory)
{
    var viewModel = viewModelFactory.Create(new MRPersonsUseCaseParams { Filter = 2 });
    ...
}
```

ViewModel is implemented by following code

```
public class MRPersons : IViewModel
{
    public MRPersons(MRPersonsUseCaseParams par)
    {
        _filter = par.Filter;
    }
}

public class MRPersonsUseCaseParams
{
    public int Filter { get; set; }
}
```

Registration in my composition root looks like:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<ViewModelFactory<MRPersons>>().As<IViewModelFactory<MRPersons>>();
builder.RegisterType<MRPersons>();
```

As you can see for each new ViewModel (now its only MRPerson) I will need to create two entries into my composition root. Thus for MRCar it will be:

```
builder.RegisterType<ViewModelFactory<MRCar>>().As<IViewModelFactory<MRCar>>();
builder.RegisterType<MRCar>();
```

I would like to automatize these registration somehow. I experimented with RegisterAssemblyTypes/AsClosedTypesOf but without success. Can somebody help me?

**EDIT:**

Based on answer codeline

```
builder.RegisterType<ViewModelFactory<MRPersons>>().As<IViewModelFactory<MRPersons>>();
```

is replaced by

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(ViewModelFactory<>)).As(typeof(IViewModelFactory<>));
```

Full automatic registration looks like:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()).Where(x => iViewModelType.IsAssignableFrom(x) && x.IsClass).AsSelf();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(ViewModelFactory<>)).As(typeof(IViewModelFactory<>));
```

For better testable solution it would be fine to even replace MRPersons by IMRPersons:

```
public class MRPersons : IViewModel, IMRPersons
{
    public MRPersons(MRPersonsUseCaseParams par)
    {
        _filter = par.Filter;
    }
}

public class MRPersonsUseCaseParams
{
    public int Filter { get; set; }
}

public interface IMRPersons 
{
}
```

Thus registration in composition root would looks like (NEED TO BE CORRECTED)

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()).Where(x => iViewModelType.IsAssignableFrom(x) && x.IsClass).As<??????>.AsSelf();
```

This would allows me to pass factory into constructor in following way:

```
public WRPersons(IViewModelFactory<IMRPersons> viewModelFactory)
{
    var viewModel = viewModelFactory.Create(new MRPersonsUseCaseParams { Filter = 2 });
    ...
}
```

**EDIT2:**
During chat with Cyril Durand he provided solution for ViewModelFactory without reference to ILifetimeScope. Here is a code:

```
public interface IViewModelFactory2<T, TU> where T : IViewModel
{
    T Create(TU par);
} 
public class ViewModelFactory2<T, TU> : IViewModelFactory2<T, TU> where T : IViewModel
{
    private readonly Func<TU, T> _factory;

    public ViewModelFactory2(Func<TU, T> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public T Create(TU par)
    {
        return _factory(par);
    } 
}
```

My original factory is Ok too since it is presented in composition root where strong references to DI container can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to register `ViewModelFactory<>` as `IViewModelFactory<>`, you can do it using the `RegisterGeneric` method.

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(ViewModelFactory<>)).As(typeof(IViewModelFactory<>));
```

Then you will be able to resolve `IViewModelFactory<MRCar>` without any other registration.

See [Registration Concepts - Open Generic Components](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#open-generic-components) for more information

---

For the second part of the question :

> For better testable solution it would be fine to even replace `MRPersons` by `IMRPersons`

It is not so easy because there is no way to know which interface to use. You can use the `AsImplementedInterfaces` which will be equivalent to `As<IMRPersons>().As<IViewModel>()` but it may be a problem if you have a lot of implemented interface.

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly())
       .Where(x => iViewModelType.IsAssignableFrom(x) && x.IsClass)
       .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Or you can use a convention that will register all `X` as`IX` but I'm not a big fan of this kind of registration.

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
        .Where(x => iViewModelType.IsAssignableFrom(x) && x.IsClass)
        .As(t => t.GetInterfaces().Where(i => i.Name.EndsWith(t.Name)));
```

---

By the way, after chatting, we figured out that you don't need a `IViewModelFactory<>` at all but you only need a dependency on `Func<TParam, T>`

Comment: Oh great I totally missed this. Your solution works well for replacing my builder.RegisterType<ViewModelFactory<MRPersons>>().As<IViewModelFactory<MRPersons>>(); line of code. For complete solution (if someone will be interested) builder.RegisterType<MRPersons>(); can be replaced by builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()).Where(x => iViewModelType.IsAssignableFrom(x) && x.IsClass).AsSelf();

Comment: Is there way how to register MRPersons, MRCar... by automatic code under their specific interfaces IMRPersons, IMRCar? (of course if this interfaces would exist). My actual registration .AsSelf() is sufficient for now but for more complex solution something like .As<IXXX>().AsSelf() where IXXX is dynamic would be great.

Comment: @user2126375 In order to resolve a `IViewModelFactory<MRPersons>` you don't need to register `MRPersons`. *Autofac* don't need this type.

Comment: @user2126375 could you edit your questions (or post a new one) with your second requirement ? it will be easier to read and I will edit my answer :)

Comment: I have to register MRPersons. Otherwise I am getting ComponentNotRegisteredException "The requested service 'DITester.DI.MRPersons' has not been registered." on return _scope.Resolve<T>(new TypedParameter(typeof(TU), par)); code line.

Comment: @user2126375 As far *Autofac* knows the type constraint, it should not be required to register this type (see https://dotnetfiddle.net/9OrQh6 for live demo). Maybe you have something specific to your case.

Comment: I created sample https://dotnetfiddle.net/zm9FsA  which demonstrates that registration for MRPersons is needed if you call Create method of that factory.

Comment: @user2126375 OK I see. See my edit for your other question. By the way, if you know `TU` you can have a dependency on `Func<TU, T>` instead of `ILifetimeScope`, this will avoid having a strong dependency on *Autofac*

Comment: I have ViewModelFactory in CompositionRoot thus it should be allowed to have strong reference on Autofac. But can you provide me more details or sample related to your Func<TU, T> proposal? I do not see how could I avoid TU in create method and passed it by another way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84468/discussion-between-cyril-durand-and-user2126375).